# What is the format of this binary file?

Tags: binary-analysis, firmware, memory, pic

I have a binary file that I found on a 3D printer that is used to program a dsPIC30F5011 microcontroller. It is responsible for some basic data encryption. The only problem is, I am not sure how this file is formatted.

It is raw binary, not like an Intel HEX file or anything. Here's a few sample lines:

---

0C4230050037600010E0801802003B21

0C424001F02C1A00370004BE6011B819

0C42506B09200982CF0200390882CFE0

0C42600441B06942520E003208003BDD

---

For the first line:

So the first byte (0x0C) is the length of the data.

The next two bytes (0x4230) is the address (I believe it is twice the address, I'll explain that further down)

Then is the data (length 0x0C in this case)  - 050037600010E0801802003Bh

The last two bytes are a Checksum  - 2's complement of the lower byte of the sum of all bytes (length through end of data).

---

The reason I believe the address listed is twice the address desired is in the [Programming Manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70102J.pdf) the Intel Hex format says:

> • AAAA - is a four-digit hexadecimal address
>   representing the starting address of the data
>   record. Format is high byte first followed by low
>   byte. The address is doubled because this format
>   only supports 8-bits. Divide the value by two to
>   find the real device address.

In fact, this format closely matches the Intel HEX format, although it isn't in ASCII format, nor does it use valid record types.

In addition, the last few commands in the file reference address 0x0008 - 0x01FF. Dividing this by 2 gives us 0x0004 - 0x00FF, which according to the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70116J.pdf) is the interrupt vector locations.

I have been poking at this for ages, and I can't seem to understand how this is actually translated to the MCU. For one thing, the addresses all increment in 16 byte increments, despite the fact that there is only 12 bytes of data in that line.

If anyone can make any sense out of this, I feel like I am at wit's end on this one.

[Here's the full file (42 KB)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WJcVrc11UX7Ps2JL9Y1RhsXNqdPd-4TJ/view?usp=sharing)

And here's some more hex if you don't feel like downloading the file:

```
0C4210889FBE8A9FBE0105780100E077
0C422004003508003C0000E0200032E3
0C4230050037600010E0801802003B21
0C424001F02C1A00370004BE6011B819
0C42506B09200982CF0200390882CFE0
0C42600441B06942520E003208003BDD
0C42708281716101648904D10884D34B
0C42808B05E80442E8F9FF3A0500371E
0C429008044489844C8B05E90442E9D1
0C42A0FBFF3A1B01070AF0A701F0A089
0C42B04F05BE4F04BE000006889FBEF4
0C42C08A9FBE8C1F783801073F013335
0C42D003866C6450E12E00326420E193
0C42E03300326150E12F00326120E118
0C42F0310032858555EB07B009002035
0C430008042005003708044489844CA0
0C43100A003106034387834B00015371
0C432081815BF8FF330203BE0800A09F
0C433008044489844CF6FF39C639DDCE
0C43408301730100321300208904D1B6
0C43500884D30998A30500320800A7D8
0C43600300A08904D10884D38B05E879
0C43708904D10884D30001EB0281D243
0C4380E4000701F0A10CF0A701F0A080
0C43901701376420E11901320801BE5A
0C43A00200BEF7FF376120E11401327B
0C43B06000B8F3FF3700002001F82780
0C43C0F0FF3704002010013703F0A2CA
0C43D0889FBE8A9FBE8C1F78F30007F8
0C43E0FA00336450E14F00326420E129
0C43F052003203826C07003B0905D02C
0C44000306D0820F540C065D02003948
0C44100200328901780306788582558D
0C442004003D0003FD8103FD8502EA5D
0C44308B8542840F7202003B6000107C
0C4440E080186011B80005EB7A28E15C
0C44500A0039060078C75DDDF707B2EE
0C44608780752D00378281710A017879
0C44706105608180D10080D38502E9E5
0C4480F9FF3B06044087844802003B23
0C4490600414E0841C0988A3070032BB
0C44A08A81718281716101648904D1FC
0C44B00884D38B05E81700370978A3B7
```